# How to create a custom pipe for filtering with multiple checkboxes? Angular 4

Tags: angular, pipe, ionic3

I have a list of statuses whose values are:
Dispatched, open, and closed. When I click on a checkbox I want to filter the results

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let s of appointmentStatus" >
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="s.checked" (click)="updateFilter(s)"></ion-checkbox>
  <ion-label >{{ s.status }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>

<div *ngFor="let a of todaysAppointments>
//list of appointments goes here
```

I have tried to come up with a way to do this with pipes, but I have not found a good example and I am rather new. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ((appDate.getDay() == currentDate.getDay()) && (appDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()) && (appDate.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear()) && this.appointments[i].status != 'Pending') {
                this.todaysAppointments.push(this.appointments[i]);
            }
            if ((appDate.getDay() < currentDate.getDay()) && (appDate.getMonth() >= currentDate.getMonth()) && (appDate.getFullYear() >= currentDate.getFullYear()) && this.appointments[i].status != 'Pending') {
                this.upcomingAppointments.push(this.appointments[i]);
            }
```

So what you did below works perfect when you only have a single array. On my html I have it divided up into Todays and upcoming appointments. So I first have the page load and show all the appointments in there corresponding sections. Then on top of that I want to filter by the checkboxes.

```
<h2 style="background-color:#387ef5">Today's Appointments</h2>
<div *ngFor="let a of todaysAppointments | filter: searchTerm" (click)="openPage(a)">

<h2 style="background-color:#387ef5">Upcoming Appointments</h2>
<div *ngFor="let a of upcomingAppointments | filter: searchTerm" (click)="openPage(a)">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Since we are dealing with two arrays, here is the original answer transformed to a pipe instead of just having the filter method in the component file.

We can also keep the `updateFilter(s)` method if you want to there add or remove filter values, or you can do it in template for the click event:

```
(click)="s.checked ? 
    filterArr.push(s.status) : filterArr.splice(filterArr.indexOf(s.status), 1)
```

I personally like having that logic in the component to keep the template clean, but that is totally up to you :)

And in the template we pass that array to the pipe:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let a of todaysAppointments | filterPipe: filterArr">
```

The pipe would look like this, where `values` is the array you want to filter, and `args` is the array with the checkboxes checked. (You'd want to reconsider the naming). We have to make the pipe impure so that it will be fired whenever changes happen.

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'filterPipe', pure: false})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(values: any, args?: any[]): any[] {
      return values = values.filter(a => {
        return args.length ? args.indexOf(a.status) != -1 : values;
      })      
    }
}
```

That should do it!

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRF8Gw46ckY8sUBoE7rd?p=preview)**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Maybe a custom pipe is not necessary here at all. You can just use the [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your click event.

Also we need to check if the checkbox is checked or not, and filter based on the values that are checked. I have here inserted them in a separate array, `filterArr`.

So in `updateFilter(s)` method we do that check first, push that filter value to the array, or remove it. Then filter by the values, or return all appointments if `filterArr` is empty:

We have a separate array that stores all appointments called `allAppointments`, from which we filter the values to `todasyAppointments`.

```ts
updateFilter(appt) {
  if(appt.checked) {
    // checkbox is checked, push to filterArr
    this.filterArr.push(appt.status)
  }
  else {
    // unchecked box, let's remove it from array
    let index = this.filterArr.indexOf(appt.status)
    this.filterArr.splice(index, 1)
  }
  // filter by the values set in filterArr, or if empty, return all appointments
  this.todaysAppointments = this.allAppointments.filter(a => {
    return this.filterArr.length ? 
           this.filterArr.indexOf(a.status) != -1 : this.allAppointments;
  })
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dEzsjBNWPOX16PcPfGLd?p=preview)**

Comment: Works Perfect! Thank you. I did leave off one detail that you may be able to help with? I have 2 sections. today and current. this filters all of them at once and leaves off my date filtering. Is there anyway to keep my date filtering? I edited above.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. as to your follow-up... I **think** I understand what you mean. Fast solution is to to first filter the dates and then *refilter* with the above code I provided. It's ugly tho. But I have a hard time piecing these codes together, since I cannot see the whole picture, just a couple of code snippets and not even sure what exactly is going on in your app.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited my code to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Not a problem. Thank you for all the help :)!

Comment: Cody, I updated answer and transformed code to pipe instead of having the method in the component :) Hopefully that works for you now :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This solution was perfect! Real life save. I appreciate the help:)

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to hear it worked out! :)