# Filter table data based on mat-tree checkbox selection, in angular 6

Tags: checkbox, angular6, angular-filters, angular-material-6, angular2-pipe

I have group checkbox which is having parent and children. I am using the following slackblitz example to achieve that:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkmjydodvnp?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

In the same page I have a table where : am showing my JSON response.

```
 "data": [
          {
            "reminderName": "Cook dinner",
            "status": "some value",
          },
          {
            "reminderName": "Read the Material Design spec",
             "status": "some value1",

          },
           {
            "reminderName": "Cook dinner",
            "status": "some value3",
          },
         {
            "reminderName": "Read the Material Design spec",
             "status": "some value4",

          }
]
```

And in table I am showing this response like this:

```
 <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of data>
            <td>{{data.reminderName}}</td>
            <td>{{data.status}}</td>
          </tr>
</tbody>
```

So here I want to refresh the table based on checkbox selection:

[image]

**If I will select Cook dinner,  only Cook dinner rows will show in  table**. Same with Read the Material Design spec also. If I will not select anything, then all data will show.

I have searched a lot on this, but not able get anything. I am struggling with this. Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit more what is expected?

Comment: If I will select Cook dinner in checkbox,then only Cook dinner rows ( "reminderName": "Cook dinner",
            "status": "some value",  &{
            "reminderName": "Cook dinner",
            "status": "some value3",
          }, )will show in table.

Comment: basically i want like this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784855/how-to-create-a-custom-pipe-for-filtering-with-multiple-checkboxes-angular-4. Here you can see plnkr demoBut how can i do this with mat-tree checkbox?